# Django bug report, different foreign key as URL parameter will cause detailed view not executing

Tags: django, debugging, url, django-class-based-views

**Edit3:**
**the culprit is re_path, not foreign key**

**Original:**

This bug is so subtle I couldn't really find a niche way to describe it, For example I have two apps, News and Blogs

In blogs.py model I have something like this:

```
class BlogType(models.Model):
    blog_type = CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_type

class Blogs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    blog_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_type = models.ForeignKey(BlogType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

here a blog_type is a foreignkey defined inside the same models.py

In blogs url.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from .views import blogspage

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blogs, name='blogs'),
    re_path(r'(?P<blog_type>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', blogspage.as_view(), name='blogspage'),
]
```

Here using the forignkey as a url parameter

And in blogs views.py

```
class blogspage(DetailView):
    model=Blogs
    template_name='blogs/blogspage.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print('Print the object if this is executed', self.get_object())
```

In Django template you would pass something like:

```
<div><a href="{% url 'blogspage' b.blog_type b.id %}">{{b.title}}</a></div>
```

Now the news model.py you have:

```
class NewsType(models.Model):
    news_type = CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_type

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    news_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    news_type = models.ForeignKey(NewsType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

The news views, news urls, news templates, are the exactly the same as blog except the name and template name, basically replacing every single "blogs" to "news"

Then here is where the bug would occur, Only one detailed view will ever execute, for example when someone clicks "`{%url "blogspage" blog.blog_type blog.id%}`" It will go to url blog/blog_type/pk but the content will be news, However, If `<foreignkey> blog_type` is removed from url parameter, Only then the detailed view of blog will execute and the correct blog content will be rendered.

news url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news, name='news'),
    re_path(r'(?P<news_type>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', newspage.as_view(), name='newspage'),
]
```

root url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
    path('blogs/',include('blogs.urls')),
] # path('news/', include('news.urls')), will not conflit
# switch the position between blogs.urls and news.urls also no conflit
```

**Edit**: [www.example.com/blogs/blog_type/1](http://www.example.com/blogs/blog_type/1) and [www.example.com/news/news_type/1](http://www.example.com/news/news_type/1) will not conflit but [www.example.com/blogs/blog_type/1](http://www.example.com/blogs/blog_type/1) and [www.example.com/news_type/1](http://www.example.com/news_type/1) will

**Edit2**: Because "" and "/blogs" bugged I automatically assume "/blogs" and "/news" will also bug, But the bug only exist between "" and "/blogs"

Comment: Can you share your root urls and news urls? Your news urls are probably included first and they conflict with the blog urls

Comment: @IainShelvington path('blogs/',include('blogs.urls')), path('news/',include('news.urls')),

Comment: Can you add the full root and news url files to the question. What is the resulting full path that is matching the wrong view?

Comment: @IainShelvington done

Comment: Could you please share the `urls.py` file.

Comment: Having a FK in a url is fine. Can you share the news urls since they are conflicting with the blog urls

Comment: @IainShelvington I showed all 3 url.py, The root, The news, The Blog, The rest are just imports

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain done

Comment: @IainShelvington on a second check, The news is not /news, It's actually "" inside the root url, Im not allowed to share the entire file, but this is pretty much it, If you change "" to news/ then the conflict would be solved, But "" and "/blog" would conflict

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain on a second check, The news is not /news, It's actually "" inside the root url, Im not allowed to share the entire file, but this is pretty much it, If you change "" to news/ then the conflict would be solved, But "" and "/blog" would conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with Django `path` and `re_path` method, where as per your scenario the `re_path` for both blogs and news URLs for `newspage` and `blogpage` are matching and django is not able to resolve the correct URL and redirect on the first matching URL.

Comment: Yes, re_path is the culprit, path solves the conflict, switch order between news.url and blogs.url in root url.py also solves the conflict, Thank You!